# How to call a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

Hey I have a problem with my method that calculates the covariance of two arrays.

There is always the error:

> undefined method 'kovarianz' for main:Object

Here is my Code:

```
rohstoff1 = "Eisen"
rohstoff2 = "Neodym"

daten_rohstoff1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
daten_rohstoff2 = [10,11,15,16,17,18]

module Enumerable
  def mean
    m = self.reduce(:+) / self.length.to_f
    return m
  end

  def covariance (dat1,dat2)
    kovar = dat1.inject(0) { |sum, x| sum + (x-dat1.mean) } *
    dat2.inject(0) { |sum, x, i| sum + (x-dat2.mean) } / dat1.length.to_f
    return kovar
  end
end

puts "Kovarianz von #{rohstoff1} und #{rohstoff2} = " +
covariance(daten_rohstoff1,daten_rohstoff2)
```

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly before posting a question. In fact, if you do that, the answer to your question becomes immediately obvious.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things wrong with what you're doing. First, you've defined an Enumerable instance method, not a class method. You won't pass in the array you are operating on but, rather, you will call `covariance` directly on the array:

`daten_rohstoff1.covariance daten_rohstoff2`

You should therefore define the method to take only one argument, namely the second array.

Second, and as mentioned before, you've defined a method `covariance` but are trying to call `kovarianz`. This, obviously, will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The method name is called `covariance` but you call `kovarianz` in the last line. Change one or the other and you should be golden.

Comment: There is a second problem which I hinted at with my comment above.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Wow, I totally missed that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the primary issue here being that you called kovarianz, as opposed to covariance, but the fact that the code is also embedded in a module means you have to call it like so:

```
Enumerable::covariance(daten_rohstoff1,daten_rohstoff2)
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: unfortunately not...there must be an other mistake in the method....but i can't find

Comment: This is incorrect. He has not defined a class method, so objects that are Enumerable will receive covariance as an instance method.

Comment: that's it....now it works...my calculation is wrong, because the result its 0.0....